# My most unused javascript according to PageSpeed.dev is react-dom. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-dom, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am using Gatsby 5 and most of my pages are using SSG. But a benchmark on [pagespeed.dev](https://pagespeed.web.dev) tells me that I need to reduce unused javascript. I used react bundle analyzer to find that biggest js chunk, and turns out it is actually the `react-dom` package. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Was the information in the "Learn how to reduce unused JavaScript" link useful?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It wasn't that useful.